# AngularJS: Access bound object from ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form that I want to use as a template. I'm using `ng-include` for this purpose.

***HTML***

```
<div ng-switch-when="insurance">
    <div ng-include="'variablePropertyForm.html'" ng-model="car.insurance"></div>
</div>
```

The `insurance` is a class that has properties that I want to bind to `input`s.  So how can I access `insurance` object from inside `variablePropertyForm.html` . template, since it's a template and I don't want to explicitly bind to `insurance.property`

Comment: `insurance` and `car.insurance` are not the same thing, are they?

Comment: no insurance is a property in the Car class

Comment: Are you trying to re-envent components? Cuase what you describe is component/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directive and define a scope in that scope you can pass that insurance object and you can define template in that directive.